# Локальный внутренний класс java

Tags: java

Изучаю java. Прочитал, что локальный внутренний класс может иметь доступ к локальным переменным, объявленных как final.
Написал код:

```
package wtf;

public class Wtf
{
    public static void doSomething()
    {
        int k = 10; // не final!!!

        class A
        {
            void print() { System.out.println(k); }
        }

        new A().print();
    }

    public static void main(String... arg)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Он работает! В чём дело?!

Comment: Вот прямо-таки [работает][1]? 


  [1]: http://ideone.com/P8TCcb

Comment: Перепроверил - не компилирует с ошибкой, указывающей на обращение к переменной 'k', которая должна быть 'final'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Рискну предположить, что пример компилировался в Java 8. Начиная с Java 8 появилось понятие **effectively final** - переменная, которая не объявлена как **final**, но которая не изменяется после инициализации.

> However, starting in Java SE 8, a local class can access local variables and parameters of the enclosing block that are final or effectively final. A variable or parameter whose value is never changed after it is initialized is effectively final.

Внутренние классы миеют доступ как к **final**, так и к **effectively final** переменным.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: Точно. Второй раз уже задаю вопрос, возникающий из-за того, что я читаю книгу, написанную до появления 8 версии. Спасибо!)